# Coded UI - The playback failed to find the control with the given search properties

Tags: visual-studio, coded-ui-tests

I am trying to run recorded test cases and its giving me this error :(

I am not able to understand this.

Please help.

```
Test Name:  CodedUITestMethod1
Test FullName:  CanopusCodedUITestProject.CodedUITest1.CodedUITestMethod1
Test Source:    d:\CanopusDev\Main\Source\Solutions\CanopusCodedUITestProject\CodedUITest1.cs : line 30
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:23.5295373

Result Message: 
Test method CanopusCodedUITestProject.CodedUITest1.CodedUITestMethod1 threw exception: 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestControlNotFoundException: The playback failed to find the control with the given search properties. Additional Details: 
TechnologyName:  'UIA'
FrameworkId:  'Wpf'
ControlType:  'Window'
Name:  'C5K Setup'
ClassName:  'HwndWrapper'
 ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
Result StackTrace:  
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback.Engine.IRPFPlayback.FindAllScreenElements(IScreenElement pScreenElementStart, String bstrQueryId, Object& pvarResKeys, Int32 cResKeys, Int32 nMaxDepth, Object[]& foundDescendants)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback.ScreenElement.FindTopLevelWindowHelper(String queryId)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback.ScreenElement.FindFromPartialQueryId(String queryId, Boolean resetSkipStep)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl..ctor(String queryId)
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.MapControlNotFoundException(COMException ex, IPlaybackContext context)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.MapAndThrowComException(COMException innerException, IPlaybackContext context)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.MapAndThrowException(SystemException exception, IPlaybackContext context)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.MapAndThrowException(SystemException exception, String queryId)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl..ctor(String queryId)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.SearchHelper.SearchTopLevelWindow(ISearchArgument topLevelSearchArg, String topLevelElementQueryId)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.SearchHelper.GetTitleUpdatedTopLevelWindow(ISearchArgument topLevelSearchArg, String queryId, IList`1 windowTitles)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.SearchHelper.GetTopLevelElement(Boolean useCache, Boolean useCacheOnly, ISearchArgument searchArg, IList`1 windowTitles, Int32& timeLeft)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.SearchHelper.GetElement(Boolean useCache, ISearchArgument searchArg)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.SearchHelper.Search(ISearchArgument searchArg)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.FindInternal()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.<Find>b__3a()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.CodedUITestMethodInvoker.InvokeMethod[T](Func`1 function, UITestControl control, Boolean firePlaybackErrorEvent, Boolean logAsAction)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.Find()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.GetPropertyPrivate(String propertyName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.<>c__DisplayClass3e.<GetProperty>b__3d()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.CodedUITestMethodInvoker.InvokeMethod[T](Func`1 function, UITestControl control, Boolean firePlaybackErrorEvent, Boolean logAsAction)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.GetProperty(String propertyName)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.ALUtility.GetTechElementFromUITestControl(UITestControl uiTestControl)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.ActionExecutorManager.GetActionExecutor(UITestControl uiControl)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Mouse.ClickImplementation(UITestControl control, MouseButtons button, ModifierKeys modifierKeys, Point relativeCoordinate)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Mouse.<>c__DisplayClass6.<Click>b__5()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.CodedUITestMethodInvoker.InvokeMethod[T](Func`1 function, UITestControl control, Boolean firePlaybackErrorEvent, Boolean logAsAction)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Mouse.Click(UITestControl control, MouseButtons button, ModifierKeys modifierKeys, Point relativeCoordinate)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Mouse.Click(UITestControl control, Point relativeCoordinate)
   at CanopusCodedUITestProject.UIMap.CreateConfiguration() in d:\CanopusDev\Main\Source\Solutions\CanopusCodedUITestProject\UIMap.Designer.cs:line 280
   at CanopusCodedUITestProject.CodedUITest1.CodedUITestMethod1() in d:\CanopusDev\Main\Source\Solutions\CanopusCodedUITestProject\CodedUITest1.cs:line 32
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the properties of the UI Component on which you recorded has changed and so it is not able to perform your recorded actions. Verify if the search properties of the component is still the same as when you recorded.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the line shown below in your stack trace:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Mouse.
Click(UITestControl control, Point relativeCoordinate)
```

This means that the CodedUI is trying to click on a control using a specific point on the screen.
For some reason it is unable to find the control it wants to click. Maybe no button exists on this specific point.
Most probably, the screen resolution of your current display device is different from the screen resolution of the display device you used to record these tests.

Comment: I know this is old but in general Coded UI tests do not refer to a coordinate or point on the screen, they refer to a coordinate on the Control. So with a button say 20 pixels wide and 10 pixels high in the middle of a screen, the coordinate will be something like x = 4, y = 3. It won't be the screen coordinates. The issue is not finding the control and there can be many reasons for that.